# What is the advantage of arrays over linked-lists when implementing stacks and queues

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack, queue

Why might we want to use an array to implement a stack and a queue, when it could be done with linked-list?
I just learned to implement stacks and queues using linked list so naturally using arrays doesn't make sense to me as of now, more specifically we could benefit `O(1)` **push** and **pop** just manipulating the **head** pointer, and without having to worry about the size of an array, unless it get's too big.

Comment: Arrays are much more memory-efficient than linked lists. They are also slightly faster at modification, except when they need to be resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing a pure stack (where you only ever access the first item), or a pure queue (where you only access the first or last), then you have O(1) access regardless of whether you've implemented it as an array or a linked list

As you mentioned, using an array has the disadvantage of having to resize when the data structure grows beyond what you've already allocated. However, you can reduce the frequency of resizing by always doubling the size. If you initially allocate enough space to handle your typical stack size, then resizing is infrequent, and in most cases one resize operation will be sufficient. And if you're worried about having too much memory allocated, you can always add some logic that will reduce the size if the amount of memory allocated far exceeds the number of items in the data structure.

Linked lists have definite benefits, but each addition to the linked list requires an allocation (and removal, a deallocation), which takes some time and also can lead to heap fragmentation. In addition, each linked list node has a `next` pointer, making the amount of memory per item more than what would be required for an array. Finally, each individual allocation has some memory overhead. All in all, a linked list of `n` items will occupy more memory than an array of `n` items.

So there are benefits and drawbacks of each approach. I won't say that either can be considered "best," but there are very good reasons to implement these data structures with arrays rather than linked lists. Correctly implemented, an array-based stack or queue can be faster and more memory efficient than a linked list implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In a array,if you want to get into some element (lets say 10)you have to write the name of the array with its index within the bracket.In a linked list though, you have to start from the head and work your way through until you get to the element.So accessing an element in an array is faster than linked lists because linked lists takes linear time to do the search.

Comment: But Thilina our concern while doing stack and queue is resizing more than we are concerned about fast access, as i mentioned in my question so why bother with arrays i mean in what situation we might want to use arrays over linked list to implement stack and also having top pointer to stack would make no sense if we could just access any element in 0(1) time so why do we even care about doing stack with array we could just model our problem in array itself no pushing or popping and yeah what if we want to pop a lot of elements so we have a lot of space going to waste but with LL we just delete

Comment: I did a little search on this. and yes using linked lists is more efficient than using arrays because it can grow during run time,Operations are Easier,no need to pre-allocate memory and Stack,Queue can be easily implemented using LL. And if we use for-each, the speed problem also get solved. In my first year at uni i also used linked list to maintain a queue and i had the same question that you have. and you are correct, for queues and stacks it's better to use LL.

Answer (score 1):

both arrays and lists have their own advantages/disadvantages; it's up to you when you need what! for example,

> in the array, **we can get the element in O(1) complexity** while you need
>   minimum **O(n) in case of the linked list**, if you consider it is an advantage
>   over the linked list, the disadvantage is **the size of the array** is needed to be
>   pre-determined this could be a problem while implementing real-world
>   problems, cause it is hard to know the size of input/list-of-input before implementing the problem, and sometimes it is required to grow/enlarge the list at runtime

therefore it can be seen that you need to consider those advantages/disadvantages based on the situation you are dealing with and need to use those data-structure generously! :D

Answer (score -1):

While linked lists offer greater flexibility for dynamic resizing and efficient insertions and deletions, array-based implementations are often preferred for their simplicity and ease of coding. Managing memory and pointers in linked lists can be more complex and error prone, particularly for beginners. In contrast, arrays typically boast less memory overhead and do not involve additional pointers which enhances their memory efficiency. Linked lists require extra memory for storing pointers or references to the next node, whereas arrays only need space for the data elements. There is another disadvantage of linked lists that is that they exhibit scattered memory locations for their nodes, resulting in more cache misses. On the other hand, arrays provide constant-time access to any element based on its index, making them especially efficient for accessing or modifying elements.
We should keep in mind that it is essential to recognize that both arrays and linked lists come with their own advantages and disadvantages. Arrays have slightly more limitations when compared with linked list in terms of dynamic resizing and flexibility.